# Map only first occurrence to destination node

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2009

I have source schema contains an element of which `maxOccurs="unbound"`.
I want to map this element to a destination element but its `maxOccurs="1"`

This case I just want to map the first occurrence of source element to destination element, and ignore the rest.

How can I do this?

Comment: Are you using a graphical mapping or a XSLT mapping?

Comment: I'm using graphic mapping (functoids).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usually use the Iteration functoid where one input is the node, the other is a fixed value of 1 and map it through a value mapping functoid, the first input being the iteration functoid the second being the source element.

Answer (score 2):

You can also do this using the Index functoid: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa547297.aspx

However, the iteration method may be easier to use if you have many nodes to map.